# Two layouts running in one screen at the same time

Tags: android

I am a new android developer and not familiar with all useful tools and how to use Android Studio.

So I am trying to develop a layout that can run two activities simultaneously, something similar to the picture that I have attached. At the same time, I want those activities to be clickable and expand independently.

Can you please give me some tips, so that I can reach my goals?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Example Picture]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two activities in the same time. You can  put the logic to two fragments. Fragments are attached to activity.

Comment: So, can't I run an camera activity lets say on background?